# How can I find the multiple version info of binary (dll or exe) from code?

Tags: binary, project, msdn, resource-files, resource-file

Some projects includes more than one version resource file, this ends up with binary which has more than one version info. When I open the binary with Visual Studio it is clearly seen that the binary has two different version info.

What I want to do is write a small program to search through bunch of binary files and find the ones which has multiple version info.

I tried to use FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo from MSDN but I could only manage to extract one version info from the binary.

I can use a little help here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with help of basic PERL scripting. The magic is to open binary like hex editor and search for the pattern "StringFileInfo", this way you can find all the version resources defined inside the binary.

This article helped a lot.
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287010

I hope this will help somebody, somehow.